# Saving UIImageView Locally

Tags: uiimageview, save, xcode8, uiimagepickercontroller

Right now I am able to have the user successfully take a picture using the camera and have their picture be uploaded into a imageview. However, if the user leaves that view controller when they eventually return the photo is no longer in that imageview. Is there anyway I am able to save the photo so that once a picture is taken and put into that imageview it is there until the user takes a different picture to replace it?

```
import UIKit

class ArsenalViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var ball1: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
 @IBAction func addPhoto1(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ball1.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        ball1.image = pickedImage
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to save the image data somewhere (i.e. UserDefaults, Core Data, a database) and then retrieve it. UserDefaults is easy, try this:

```
    //Encoding
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage!)! as NSData

    //Saved image
    UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "savedImage")

    //Decode
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedImage") as! NSData{
        myImageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
    }
```

Encoding and saving image should happen right after updating your image and decoding should be done once the view has loaded all of its elements (viewDidAppear method).

After encoding and saving the image once, you can decode it anytime, even if the user left the VC and came back.

Comment: I am still getting an error message stating Cannot convert value of type 'UIImageView!' to expected argument type 'UIImage' when implementing the first line under //Encoding

Comment: Access the image with: imageView.image (i.e. ball1.image)

Comment: I would like to ask your opinion on where to implement the above code. It is working with one slight issue. When the user leaves that VC and return the image has been rotated for some reason any explanation?

Comment: "Encoding" and "Saved Image" code should go inside the imagePickerController function, right after ball1.image = pickedImage, because that's when the image is updated. "Decode" code should go inside viewDidLoad method so it loads every time the VC loads. The image rotation is solved by replacing "UIImagePNGRepresentation" with "UIImageJPEGRepresentation" because JPEG's automatically use rotation flags.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I have one last question. When I put the "Decode" portion of code inside the viewDidLoad method the app crashes because it is unexpectedly finding nil when unwrapping optional value. Is there some way to avoid this?

Comment: You're welcome! The app crash is solved by using optional chaining to avoid nil values and I believe decoding is best done inside viewDidAppear; improving my previous suggestion. I've updated the answer with these advances. If you need more help, don't hesitate to ask more questions.

Comment: If my answer was useful, consider marking it as accepted so other developers with the same problem know it's a solution. @H.Bridge